# undefined with promise async / await

Tags: javascript, meteor, promise, async-await

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with the code when calling promise with map? I get undefined output.
P.S this is for meteor.

```
async function getResUrl(item, url){

  let res = await HTTP.call("GET", url, function(err, res){
    return res.statusCode;
  });
  console.log(res);
  return res;
}

function getUrlRes(_screenName) {

  let getRes = Promise.all(_.map(Object.keys(social), function(item){
    let url = social[item]+"/"+_screenName;

    getResUrl(item, url);

  })).then(function(result){
    return result
  });

return getRes;
}
```

Comment: Why use `_.map()` instead of the built-in `.map()`?

Comment: `getResUrl` ... `getUrlRes` You enjoy tormenting dyslexics, don't you.

Comment: Does `HTTP.call` return a promise, looks like it has a callback, and you just return from that ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `getResUrl()` returns a promise, change this:

```
getResUrl(item, url);
```

to

```
return getResUrl(item, url);
```

You have to return the promise so `map()` can accumulate the promises.

It looks like you also may need to properly promisify `HTTP.call()` so that it returns a promise.